# I have to change the background of div of previously checked radio buttons? But i am getting problems

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am getting a problem in changing the css of the div of previously checked radio buttons. This is my jQuery code on load page:

```
var check = jQuery('input:radio').is(':checked');  
if (check == true) {
    //jQuery('input:radio').closest('.swatch').find('div.new').removeClass('new');
    jQuery('.swatch-element').addClass('new');
} else {
    jQuery('.swatch-element').removeClass('new');
}
```

My list structure:

```
<div data-option-index="0" class="swatch clearfix swatch-0">
    <div class="header">Weight</div>
        <div class="swatch-element 1-pound available new" data-value="1 Pound">
            <input type="radio" checked="" value="1 Pound" name="option-0" id="swatch-0-1-pound">
            <label for="swatch-0-1-pound">
                1 Pound
                <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1313/8977/t/3/assets/soldout.png?10509341804900951712" class="crossed-out">
            </label>
        </div>
        <script>
            jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .1-pound').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .1-pound').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
        </script>

        <div class="swatch-element 2-pounds available new" data-value="2 Pounds">
            <input type="radio" value="2 Pounds" name="option-0" id="swatch-0-2-pounds">
            <label for="swatch-0-2-pounds">
                2 Pounds
                <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1313/8977/t/3/assets/soldout.png?10509341804900951712" class="crossed-out">
            </label>
        </div>
        <script>
            jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .2-pounds').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
        </script>
        <script>
            jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="0"] .2-pounds').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
        </script>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to check each element?i am getting confused in the structure and selector of jQuery.

Comment: You really don't need a `<script>` for each line of your script...

Comment: What do you mean by *"previously checked radio buttons"* - you only seem to have 2 radio buttons. The button which is not selected? Or the ones the user had selected but not selected right now?

Comment: while i am loading the page . there is one of theme is selected. So i have to change the background of selected radio button on load.Got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want :

```
$("input:radio").each(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
     $('.swatch-element').addClass('new');
 }
 else {
     $('.swatch-element').removeClass('new');
 }
});
```

Is that ok?

You can use `<script>` for several JavaScript lines.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, to highlight the radio selected by default by adding class to it's parent, you can use the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method like:

```
$(function(){
  $('input:radio:checked').closest('.swatch-element').addClass('selected');
  //------------------------- whatever class you want------------^
});
```

Since the `<div>` is the direct parent you can also use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) method like:

```
$(function(){
  $('input:radio:checked').parent().addClass('selected');
  //------------------------- whatever class you want------------^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so check this code

CSS :

```
.change{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color:#f1f1f1;
    }
```

Html part :

```
<div class="change"><input type="radio" >hello</div>
<div class="change"><input type="radio" checked>hello</div>
<div class="change"><input type="radio" >hello</div>
<div class="change"><input type="radio" checked>hello</div>
```

Now Javascript :

```
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).parents('.swatch-element').addClass('selected');
    });
```

Check this fidde : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at3j7y0m/)